# Want to omit some values from TCP packet

Tags: matlab, tcp, processing

I have successfully created the tcp connection between processing and matlab. I am using oscp5 library for that. I am sending an array containing 3 float values from processing.

But in Matlab, I am getting 5 extra values. Please advise how I can omit these values.

Please note that I can't use another library.

Also, someone suggest me, while creating message, I have assigned it a label "/test". When matlab's server gets the message, it will read this as well as the data in your package as assembled by oscP5. So, I have to teach matlab how to interpret that data. Hence, I need to go to the oscP5 website and review java docs and the source code to understand the packaging format. Here the link

http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/

You can see the code below.

```
-------------Processing Code-------------
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscMessage myMessage;
OscP5 oscP5tcpClient;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  oscP5tcpClient = new OscP5( this, "141.44.219.204", 1234, OscP5.TCP);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

    OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("test\");
    myMessage.add(new float[] {123.2, 134.5, 52.5}); ==>> Sent Message 

    oscP5tcpClient.send(myMessage);
    print(50+sin(a)*40.0);
  }
  -----------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------MATLAB Code----------------------------
>> tcpipServer = tcpip('141.44.219.161',1234,'NetworkRole','Server');
>> fopen(tcpipServer)
>> data = fread(tcpipServer, 8 , 'float32')

data =

           0  ===>> want to omit
      0.0000  ===>> want to omit
           0  ===>> want to omit
    123.2000
    134.5000
     52.5000
      0.0000  ===>> want to omit
           0  ===>> want to omit

>> 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What exact values are you sending? What exact values are you getting? If it's always the same extras, can't you just skip over them yourself?

Comment: Not sure if related, but matlab documentation suggests `'float32=>float32'` instead of just `'float32'` if you want to collect into 'single' precision variables. Also, I'm sure this is the case, but are you sure the java float is 32-bits in your machine? (I think this is not guaranteed to be the case so you can check).

Comment: also, yes, what does printing `myMessage` give in java, and what does `fread(tcpipServer, 'char=>char')` give in matlab? (i.e. I wonder if your data comes with some sort of header?)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou....'float32=>float32' is not a valid precision in fread() [Please share the link where you have read this maybe i am missing that]. Also, for characters, matlab have fscanf() but not sure.

Comment: @KevinWorkman ....my actual intention is to send continuously x and y coordinates from processing and receive in matlab. But the problem is i am getting the oscp5 packet label also (which is obvious). i am just looking for a way that i can remove this label in first place (which i donot know how) and will get the relevant data only. And yes, you are right i can remove the label myself after receving the whole data in matlab.